# Regular expression to grab a specific section of sample

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I am trying to find/match the number sequences in bold in the example lines below using regular expressions.

> 2520222 Rubble,Barney **1134525**
>
> 1524356 Mudd,Harry S **14-40525**  111.11
>
> 2324316 Mudd,Mary R **12-40000**

The closest that I've come is

```
\d{0,2}-?\d+$
```

But that only works when the section I want to capture is at the end of the line because of the $. If there is an unwanted item at the end of the line (see line #3) it will always be a decimal. Is there a way find that and step back one group to the correct sequence? Is it even possible in RegEx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use look arounds in a regex like this:

```
(?<= )[\d-]+(?=\s|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1eca6/2)**

[image]

If you don't want to use lookarounds, then you could use a regex like this:

```
,.*\s([\d-]+)(?:$|\s)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1eca6/3)**

Comment: Out of curiosity, which tool are you using to generate the diagram?